# Chart JS - Line chart with days in x-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to draw chart with the x-axis to be in day with 12.00 AM. It is using quite alot of point

This is my desire output
[image]

But this is the output I am getting:

[image]

I am getting this weird "Object object" in the x-axis

```
        //I have truncated the stats as it exceeded the max length in SO            
        let response = '{"stats":[ { "time":"2018-10-24 13:30:02", "occupation":"54", "liveness":"78", "efficiency":"48", "pms":"up" }, { "time":"2018-10-24 13:45:02", "occupation":"55", "liveness":"78", "efficiency":"50", "pms":"up" }, { "time":"2018-10-24 14:00:01", "occupation":"56", "liveness":"76", "efficiency":"51", "pms":"up" }, { "time":"2018-10-24 14:15:02", "occupation":"56", "liveness":"77", "efficiency":"52", "pms":"up" }, { "time":"2018-10-24 14:30:01", "occupation":"56", "liveness":"78", "efficiency":"53", "pms":"up" }, { "time":"2018-10-24 14:45:01", "occupation":"57", "liveness":"79", "efficiency":"56", "pms":"up" }, { "time":"2018-10-24 15:00:02", "occupation":"57", "liveness":"79", "efficiency":"56", "pms":"up" }]}';
        let parsedResponse = ($.parseJSON(response));

        let stats = parsedResponse.stats;
        let arrayDays = [];
        $.each(parsedResponse.days, function(key, value) {
            arrayDays.push(moment(value).toDate());
        });

        let statLength  = stats.length;
        let occupation  = [];
        let liveness    = [];
        let efficiency  = [];
        let labels      = [];

        parsedResponse = undefined;

        let dataDateTime        = '';
        let dataDateTimeFormat  = 'MMM DD HH:mm A';
        for(let index = 0; index < statLength; index++) {
            dataDateTime = moment(stats[index]['time']).format(dataDateTimeFormat);

            // occupation.push({'x': dataDateTime, 'y': stats[index]['occupation']});
            // liveness.push({'x': dataDateTime, 'y': stats[index]['liveness']});
            // efficiency.push({'x': dataDateTime, 'y': stats[index]['efficiency']});

            occupation.push(stats[index]['occupation']);
            liveness.push(stats[index]['liveness']);
            efficiency.push(stats[index]['efficiency']);
            labels.push({dataDateTime});
        }

        let fill = false;
        let color = Chart.helpers.color;
        let data = {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Screens',
                pointRadius: 0,
                tension: 0,
                backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.green).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
                fill: fill,
                data: liveness
            },{
                label: 'Occupation',
                pointRadius: 0,
                tension: 0,
                backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                fill: fill,
                data: occupation
            },{
                label: 'Efficiency',
                pointRadius: 0,
                tension: 0,
                backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.orange).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
                borderColor: window.chartColors.orange,
                fill: fill,
                data: efficiency
            }]
        };

        let chartOptions = {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true,
                        stepSize: 10,
                        max: 100
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Percentage'
                    }

                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    //editing this will mess it up pretty bad
                }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(value, index) {
                        return index.datasets[value.datasetIndex].label + ": " + value.yLabel;
                    },
                }
            }
        };
```

The thing is, I tried several times to edit the x-axis option but it keeps messing the output

Comment: Please, in which part of the code you set the property that would be the x-axis label? And which variable/property holds the day/hour that should be the x-axis label?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I do not need the title, I need the date and it to be by day 12.00AM

Comment: ok, the string/label... I mean, can you show where should it be setted? I don't know chart.js, but I know JS and maybe I can help if i understand where you should set it

Comment: @CalvinNunes I do not set them(they usually mess it up), I let chart js automatically set it for me as the example here http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/line.html

Comment: You might want to create a fiddle of this

Comment: @Brian alright. Will do it in weekend. time to go home. thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `dataDateTime`, for some reason, you are pushing it as an object in the label value, right here:

`labels.push({dataDateTime});`

That's why you are getting an `X-axis` label with `[Object object]`... You have two possible solutions:

1.**Change the push:**
`labels.push(dataDateTime);`

2.**Add a callback to the `xAxes[0].ticks` property:**

```
xAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    callback: function(value, index, values) {
       return value.dataDateTime
    }
  }
}]
```

Both will work well (I tested), you also can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/calvin_nunes/mw1vLcka/) that I made, to check it working (using the first solution)